# probleme with a display hook PRESTASHOP

Tags: php, content-management-system, prestashop, smarty

I' m working on /miniature/produt.tpl and I want to render some information about my seller (name.. rating..).

I m using at the same time a marketplace module, and its already rendering the information in a hook  {hook h='displayProductAdditionalInfo' product=$product}in the /catalog/product.tpl page.
I want to do the same thing, so I tried to make the same call but it is printing nothing.
When I debug with a die in the hook function it is rendering the die function.
any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where did you try the call to displayProductAdditionalInfo from?

Usually and recommended this has to be done from within a module you have to create.

Comment: Actualy the hook function is created in a new module.